# How to reduce Size of app while using Mlkit translation library

Tags: google-mlkit

I am using google ML-Kit for on device translation using latest library:- com.google.mlkit:translate:17.0.1. Library work pretty well for translation but only issue is of it's size i.e. Before using this library my app's size was 8Mb and after using this size became 66.8 Mb which is huge for me.

Currently i am using only English to Hindi translation and in future will use Indian languages. So is there any way to reduce size or we can import library only for specific language translation like in my case English to Hindi only.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the after-use size, is that size right after you build the apk or the app size shown in Settings - Apps after you use the app?

If the former, it may because you include the native library for all ABIs in the apk. Please check the following doc to learn more about ABI and how to reduce apk size: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

If the latter, it could be the size of the models. The Translate API will download required models when being used. You can search "download" on this page to learn more: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/translation/android